# Error when predicting logistic regression

Tags: python

I am currently doing a project on predicting binary outputs. I obtained my code resource from http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-28.html and https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60, where the aim is, based on the training dataset, 'train_dataset02_process.csv', predict for each observation in the test_dataset, "test_dataset.csv" whether each observation is yes or no. The train dataset has 18123 observations but the test dataset has 9679 observations.

There are a few variables that affect the outcome, as seen in the code. I used PCA to cluster these variables together, then used logistic regression to predict the outcome. The last line of code however, does not run and keeps giving me an error:

```
ValueError: X has 43 features per sample; expecting 13
```

So, I have my code here,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_train = pd.read_csv('train_dataset02_process.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv("test_dataset.csv")

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#Variables affecting outcome
LEVEL_T1 = df_train['LEVEL_T1']
LEVEL_T2 = df_train['LEVEL_T2']
LEVEL_T3 = df_train['LEVEL_T3']
LEVEL_T4 = df_train['LEVEL_T4']
LEVEL_T5 = df_train['LEVEL_T5']
LEVEL_T6 = df_train['LEVEL_T6']
LEVEL_T7 = df_train['LEVEL_T7']
PRESSURE_J280 = df_train['PRESSURE_J280']
PRESSURE_J269 = df_train['PRESSURE_J269']
PRESSURE_J300 = df_train['PRESSURE_J300']
PRESSURE_J256 = df_train['PRESSURE_J256']
PRESSURE_J289 = df_train['PRESSURE_J289']
PRESSURE_J415 = df_train['PRESSURE_J415']
PRESSURE_J302 = df_train['PRESSURE_J302']
PRESSURE_J306 = df_train['PRESSURE_J306']
PRESSURE_J307 = df_train['PRESSURE_J307']
PRESSURE_J317 = df_train['PRESSURE_J317']
PRESSURE_J14 = df_train['PRESSURE_J14']
PRESSURE_J422 = df_train['PRESSURE_J422']
FLOW_PU1 = df_train['FLOW_PU1']
FLOW_PU2 = df_train['FLOW_PU2']
FLOW_PU3 = df_train['FLOW_PU3']
FLOW_PU4 = df_train['FLOW_PU4']
FLOW_PU5 = df_train['FLOW_PU5']
FLOW_PU6 = df_train['FLOW_PU6']
FLOW_PU7 = df_train['FLOW_PU7']
FLOW_PU8 = df_train['FLOW_PU8']
FLOW_PU9 = df_train['FLOW_PU9']
FLOW_PU10 = df_train['FLOW_PU10']
FLOW_PU11 = df_train['FLOW_PU11']
FLOW_V2 = df_train['FLOW_V2']
STATUS_PU1 = df_train['STATUS_PU1']
STATUS_PU2 = df_train['STATUS_PU2']
STATUS_PU3 = df_train['STATUS_PU3']
STATUS_PU4 = df_train['STATUS_PU4']
STATUS_PU5 = df_train['STATUS_PU5']
STATUS_PU6 = df_train['STATUS_PU6']
STATUS_PU7 = df_train['STATUS_PU7']
STATUS_PU8 = df_train['STATUS_PU8']
STATUS_PU9 = df_train['STATUS_PU9']
STATUS_PU10 = df_train['STATUS_PU10']
STATUS_PU11 = df_train['STATUS_PU11']
STATUS_V2 = df_train['STATUS_V2']
features = pd.DataFrame([LEVEL_T1,LEVEL_T2,LEVEL_T3,LEVEL_T4,LEVEL_T5,LEVEL_T6,LEVEL_T7,PRESSURE_J280,PRESSURE_J269,PRESSURE_J300,  PRESSURE_J256,PRESSURE_J289,PRESSURE_J415,PRESSURE_J302,PRESSURE_J306,PRESSURE_J307,PRESSURE_J317,PRESSURE_J14,PRESSURE_J422,FLOW_PU1,FLOW_PU2,FLOW_PU3,FLOW_PU4,FLOW_PU5,FLOW_PU6,FLOW_PU7,FLOW_PU8,FLOW_PU9,FLOW_PU10,FLOW_PU11,FLOW_V2,STATUS_PU1,STATUS_PU2,STATUS_PU3,STATUS_PU4,STATUS_PU5,STATUS_PU6,STATUS_PU7,STATUS_PU8,STATUS_PU9,STATUS_PU10,STATUS_PU11,STATUS_V2])

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(df_train)
train_img = scaler.transform(df_train)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# Make an instance of the Model
pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(train_img)
train_img = pca.transform(train_img)

from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing
log_model = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
logisticRegr.fit(train_img, df_train['ATT_FLAG'])

test_preds = logisticRegr.predict(df1[0:18122])
```

Would anyone be able to give me any insights on how to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: The logisticRegr learns the relationship between X1, X2, ...Xn and Y. The error tells you that you trained the algorithm on 13 features but later you give it 43, so it doesn't know anymore what to do. The number of observations (`n_samples`) is not important, but the number of features must be constant. You said you were using a PCA. Have also applied the exact same PCA to the test data set?

Comment: At a guess: you've just transformed your `train_img` using PCA from 43 to 13 dimensions, and you train regressor on this reduced `train_img`. Yet in that last line, you perform a prediction providing the original input dataset, which has 43 dimensions. You probably need to transform this dataset as well to 13 dimensions.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to resolve the problem by implementing the following lines of code:

`scaler = StandardScaler()

# Standardizing the features
scaler.fit(df_train)
train_img = scaler.transform(df_train)
test_img = scaler.transform(df1)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# Make an instance of the Model
pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(train_img)
train_img = pca.transform(train_img)
test_img = pca.transform(test_img)`

But it still gave me: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9769,43) (44,) (9769,43)`